# nginx symlinks permission denied / 403 Forbidden on Mac OSX

Tags: nginx, mac-osx, mac, symbolic-link, symlink

So I have an nginx server running on Mac OSX and I am trying to create a symlink in my nginx www directory from somewhere else. In the browser I get the wonderful `403 Forbidden` error.
I have also tried chmod'ing my life away for the past few hours.

There doesn't seem to be anything on the stack about it. One thing concerns me is that I am not sure if symlinks are directly supported by ngninx on Mac.

Trying to use `disable_symlink` directive results in:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "disable_symlinks" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44`
```

Some info about my setup:
`nginx -v` : `nginx version: nginx/1.4.2`

To create the symlink I do the following:

```
cd /Users/levi/www
ln -s "/Users/levi/Desktop/.../client" "/Users/levi/www/client"
```

The error in the log:

```
[error] 11864#0: *7 open() "/Users/levi/www/client" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /client HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if there's any more information I can give you.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 7 with nginx 1.4.0: `unknown directive "disable_symlinks"`

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into something similar.  Turns out one of the directories along the way to the target had too-restrictive permissions.  `chmod 755 $HOME` fixed it in my case.

Comment: Just a warning; this means anyone with access to your machine (other users, SSH, etc) will be able to access your home folder and, potentially, anything private within it.

Answer (score 2):

I can verify that symlinks with nginx work on the mac with nginx 1.2.7.

Symlink created as:

```
ln -s /Users/salpher/nginxtest /usr/local/opt/nginx/html/
```

Do you have any content in the 'client' directory?  Directory index browsing is disabled by default and you will see a 403 forbidden if there is no index page and your url does not point at a particular content file.

If it's directory browsing that you're after you can enable that in your directory config with autoindex on;

```
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there are two files in the 'client' directory. Autoindex is turned on. I do not have an index file for the directory though or the root directive. I don't think that's creating the problem though.

Comment: Can't seem to edit my other comment. I tried adding the root directive and an index directive, neither and both did not fix the issue. I also found that I get the same "permission denied" message when trying to point '/client' in the nginx config to the original 'client' directory.

Comment: Do you also get a 403 when your URL points at an html file or something other than a directory?

Comment: Yes I do. For example when trying to go to http://localhost/client/somefile.html

Comment: If you haven't already you might check out http://serverfault.com/questions/218583/403-forbidden-error-on-mac-osx-apache-and-nginx .  Sounds similar.  Also, how did you install nginx?  Was it a binary installation or did you grab the code and compile?  If it was a binary installation where did it come from?  For reference my test setup came from a brew installation.

Comment: I honestly can't remember, but if I had to take a guess it would be that I installed it with homebrew. Nothing fancy just 'brew install nginx'. But i'll take a look at that link.

Comment: It seems that was the issue. By default in OSX the Desktop permissions for 'everyone' are set to 'No Access'. In finder, then clicking info, sharing & permissions - set 'everyone' to read only. Fixed the issue. I am sure this is a major security issue. If you could write up a detailed answer on how to properly allow this directory to be used by the nginx user (by default 'nobody') from the command line, I will give you the answer.